# UIView: Inheriting Touch

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

**Example 1:**
When invoking 3D Touch on app icon, you are able to make selections without lifting the finger up.

**Example 2**
Long pressing on a keyboard key allowing you to drag in to different selections without lifting finger up.

[image]
[image]

If the app icon is the first view and the pop up is the second view, how can I transfer touch down from first to second view?

Comment: I think Override touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded, touchesCancelled. And passing touch event to next responder. IDK its correct or not.

Comment: From the first view?

Comment: What's your actual need? Do you want create the exact feature 2 custom `uivews`? or (`uiview` & `uitableview` )

Comment: Im trying to implement 3D Touch Popup from a given UIView.  Once the 2nd View pops up, I want the use to be able to select an element without lifting the finger.  Exactly the behavior in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a view loses control of the touches when the fingers leave its area. But if you set [`isMultipleTouchEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622519-ismultipletouchenabled) to `true`, it will keep control over touches if the finger leave its area. If you use a button or another `UIControl` you can assign actions to `touchDragExit`, `touchUpOutside` or `touchDragOutside` etc. to handle events outside of the control.